# $-1\leq\pm 2x\sqrt{1-x^2}\leq1\;\forall\;x\in[-1,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis

How to prove without using functions these two inequalities $\forall\; x\in[-1, 1]$:

$$-1\leq 2x\sqrt{1-x^2}\leq1$$

$$-1\leq -2x\sqrt{1-x^2}\leq1$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $x \in [-1,1]$, we can let $x = \sin(t)$, where $t \in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. Hence,
$$2x \sqrt{1-x^2} = 2\sin(t) \cos(t) = \sin(2t)$$
which clearly $\in [-1,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Square $2x\sqrt{1-x^2}$, and complete the square.